# How to correctly do XML validation with XSD file?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

im trying to validate an xml file with a schema .xsd and it's not working. I'm in Eclipse and when I right click ->validate the XML file, it doesn't give any error (I made sure to include an error in the Schema file).

I've got

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<rootname xmlns="urn:target"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:SchemaLocation="urn:target
                                file:./target.xsd">
```

at the top of my xml file and ive got

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="urn:target"
            xmlns="urn:target"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

at the top of my .xsd file.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a *minimal*, but ***complete*** [mcve] exhibiting the problem.

Comment: You have two default namespace in `rootname` - `xmlns="urn:target" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. I believe it is not proper configuration at least because you have duplicated attributes,.

Comment: @AlexeyR., good point.  OP should (at least) change `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` to `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` Posting a [mcve] would allow us to check for any further issues.